# Creating a user signup and a django-user at the same time. Save method is adding user regardless of valid form

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I have a team registration app. A user signs up to be a part of the team. When they do so, the view adds a team member and adds the user into the auth db.

However, when the team model returns invalid data, the user.save() method is adding the username, password and email.

So, when a user corrects the team registration, and clicks submit, they are now told that the username is taken.

What I want to have happen is the username etc is added AFTER the teammember has been validated.

Any suggestions?

Here's the view:

```
def register(request, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SimpleRegForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
            form.save()

            # Send an email to the admin letting them know that a person registered
            subject = render_to_string('teamregistration/email_subject.txt')
            message = render_to_string('teamregistration/email_body.txt',
                                       {'first_name':form.cleaned_data['first_name'], 'last_name':form.cleaned_data['last_name'], 'tbi_region':form.cleaned_data['tbi_region']})
            recipients = ['XXXXXX@XXXXXX.XXX', 'XXXXXX@XXXXXX.XXX']
            send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, recipients)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tbi-team-register/registration-submitted/')
    else:
        form = SimpleRegForm()

    return render_to_response('teamregistration/form.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I don't see where team membership processing is done in this example, just the user registration form is processed (and twice, it appears).  This seems to me to be a simple precedence issue: ensure the data for both is correct, then save both.  If you can't do that, you might want to look into Django's "Commit On Success" decorator, which will cause all transactions within a given view to roll back automatically if any one transaction fails.

Comment: that's an even more elegant answer. But... dork that I am. All I had to do was remove the user.save(). That solved the problem, restricting the save to the form.save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is remove the user.save().